# linq-to-sql .All() or .Any() to find all items that match criteria

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| FruitID | BasketID | FruitType |
|   23    |    2     |    1      |
|   24    |    5     |    1      |  
|   25    |    2     |    1      |
|   26    |    5     |    2      |
```

I'm writing a query where I'm passing a list of `BasketIDs` and I want to get back a new list of `BasketIDs` that contains only baskets that have `FruitID` where all `FruitTypes` are equal to 1. For instance, if I pass in BasketIDs 2 and 5, I get back only 2 because basket 5 has FruitID 26 that's of FruitType 2.

This is what I have:

```
var TheQuery = (from f in MyDC.TableFruits
                where TheListOfBasketIDs.Contains(f.BasketID) &&
                // need help here 
                select f.BasketID).ToList();
```

Thanks for your suggestions on how to write the filter.

Comment: I seems more intuitive to write it the other way around, eg: find records matching FruitTypes = 1, then filter on the BasketIds.

Comment: @leppie: there could be 10s of millions of FruitID so I think it'd be better to first filter for those that are inside the basket no? That's why I'm first doing a where with .Contains()

Comment: If it is LINQ2SQL, the SQL server will handle it, but probably not a good idea for LINQ2Entities ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group fruits by `BasketID` to verify all fruits from basket have `FruitType` equal to `1`:

```
var TheQuery = (from f in MyDC.TableFruits                  
                group f by f.BasketID into g
                where TheListOfBasketIDs.Contains(g.Key) &&
                      g.All(x => x.FruitType == 1)
                select g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: @frenchie actually you can move contains part before grouping `from f in MyDC.TableFruits.Where(x => TheListOfBasketIDs.Contains(x.BasketID))` but I don't think there will be big performance benefit. You can try both queries :)